# ERROR TypeError: i.createShadowRoot is not a function on Angular Web Component?

Tags: angular, typescript, web-component, angular-elements

I'm attempting a basic Angular Web Component. I created a github repository that shows the approach here:

https://github.com/fireflysemantics/fs-gist

This is the component:
https://github.com/fireflysemantics/fs-gist/blob/master/src/app/fs-gist/fs-gist.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'fs-gist',
  template: `
    <p>
      fs-gist works!
    </p>
  `,
  styles: [
  ],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.Native
})
export class FsGistComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

And this is the module:
https://github.com/fireflysemantics/fs-gist/blob/master/src/app/app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { FsGistComponent } from './fs-gist/fs-gist.component';

import { Injector } from '@angular/core';
import { createCustomElement } from '@angular/elements';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    FsGistComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  entryComponents: [FsGistComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
  constructor(private injector: Injector) {}

  ngDoBootstrap() {
    const el = createCustomElement(
      FsGistComponent, 
      { injector: this.injector });
    customElements.define('fs-gist', el);
  }
}
```

And these are the build scripts in `package.json`

https://github.com/fireflysemantics/fs-gist/blob/master/package.json

```
    "b": "ng build --prod --output-hashing=none",
    "c": "bash -c 'cat dist/fs-gist/{runtime-es5,polyfills-es5,main-es5}.js > fs-gist.js'",
    "c1": "bash -c 'cat dist/fs-gist/{runtime-es2015,polyfills-es2015,main-es2015}.js > fs-gist2015.js'",
    "p": "npm run b && npm run c",
    "p1": "npm run b && npm run c1",
    "cp-fs-gist": "cp fs-gist.js ../wctest/src/assets/js/"
```

Running `npm run p` will create the web component `fs-gist` in the root folder.

I then copied that into the `src/assets/js/` folder of this test project:

https://github.com/fireflysemantics/wc-test

When the application is loaded the the console logs:

> fs-gist.js:1 ERROR TypeError: i.createShadowRoot is not a function
>       at new n (fs-gist.js:1)
>       at e.value (fs-gist.js:1)
>       at fs-gist.js:1
>       at n.value (fs-gist.js:1)
>       at e.value (fs-gist.js:1)
>       at e.value (fs-gist.js:1)
>       at HTMLElement.value (fs-gist.js:1)
>       at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone-evergreen.js:364)
>       at Object.onInvoke (fs-gist.js:1)
>       at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone-evergreen.js:363)

I've included polyfills for web components in `polyfills.js`:

```
import "@webcomponents/custom-elements/src/native-shim";
import "@webcomponents/custom-elements/custom-elements.min";
import '@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/custom-elements-es5-adapter.js'
```

and I've added web component loading to `index.html`:

```
  <script src="webcomponents/webcomponents-loader.js"></script>
  <script>   
  if ( !window.customElements ) 
  { document.write('<!--') } 
  </script>
  <script src="webcomponents/custom-elements-es5-adapter.js"></script> 
  <!-- ! KEEP ME -->
```

Any ideas?

Also just to see whether I could get this working in a minimal environment I took the `fs-gist` web component that the first project produces and made a minimal javascript stackblitz with it.

The demo imports the web components polyfill from a CDN.

This is it:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-custome-element-test

The following error is produced:

> ERROR
>   Error: Failed to execute 'define' on 'CustomElementRegistry': the name "fs-gist" has already been used with this registry

### Bug Report

I think there is a bug in the Angular compilation of the web component.

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/17448

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The components View Encapsulation needs to be `ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom` (See above mentioned bug report for reference):

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'fs-gist',
  template: `
    <p>
      fs-gist works!
    </p>
  `,
  styles: [
  ],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom
})
export class FsGistComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```